# CSS or JavaScript causing search results box to appear before keypress

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, dom

I have a form that renders on several pages that is basically a fuzzy search that populates a dropdown UL with results to choose from as you type (from a database). The functionality is there, however on 'focus' a 6px, empty "dropdown" appears with no results. Upon inspection, it is the div that contains the ul for the search results (see screen shots below). Unfortunately, I have come into this project half way through and have, so far, been unable to detect how or why the dropdown is appearing before there are results to populate it. I have checked all the classes, and inspected the JS files. None of them are creating the 6px, empty box, and one of the classes is actually setting the dropdown div to 'display: none', which I am guessing gets overridden somewhere when focus is applied. Chrome inspector has been unable to provide me with any information as to what class is causing it, except that the div itself has a height of 6px. The site is utilizing a custom CSS stylesheet, jQuery (1.9) and jQuery UI (1.10.2).

[image: Search without focus]
[image: Search with focus and 6px dropdown]

Comment: can you share any code?

Comment: This will be impossible to solve without some sort of live demo.

Comment: Wish I could. NDA stuff. Some designer created a bunch of custom stuff and it's like swimming in mud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description I think that you are using `focus` event to show dropdown, you should be using the [keydown](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) event. Even google does it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use something like preventdefault.could that be a bubbling problem?